# get request works on postman but not with file_gets_content and cURL from php

Tags: php, curl, postman

Here is the url below, tried both with the method file_get_contents and curl...doesn't work from php script but works fine with postman.
Any idea why so???

> https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q= select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (SELECT woeid FROM geo.places WHERE text="(28.56,77.32)") and u='c'&format=json

cURL request is as follows:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 

$output = curl_exec($ch);   

// convert response
$output = json_decode($output);

// handle error; error output
if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200) {

  var_dump($output);
}
echo curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: file_get_contents does not work with https

Comment: please add your curl code for the request.

Comment: edited..with curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this one. The difference is that the url is url encoded:

```
$url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%20select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(SELECT%20woeid%20FROM%20geo.places%20WHERE%20text=%22(28.56,77.32)%22)%20and%20u=%27c%27&format=json';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
```